# What is going on with the variable? Subquery not being executed?

Tags: mysql, subquery

I think I may be onto something. But I'm still having a problem. What am I missing here to define the Task1?. Some info you may need is I am using MySqli PDO.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Tasks 
(FirstName, LastName, 
ListName, Phone, 
HomeAddress, 
Task1) VALUES ('$FirstName', 
'$LastName', '$ListName', 
'$Phone', 
'$HomeAddress', 
(SELECT Task1 FROM 
 AutoPilotTaskLists WHERE 
 ListName = 
'$ListName'))";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($conn->query($sql) === 
TRUE) {
echo "Here is the 
information";
$Task1<br />
";
```

This outputs:

Notice: Undefined variable: Task1 in /filepath/ on line 57

**EDIT: Just to provide more info on the progress of discovering the solution.**

PHP Version is 7.3.33. The following is the entire code (after some edits from the original above). This doesn't work and throws an error saying: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /Filepath/testpage.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /Filepath/testpage.php on line 34

```
<?php
$servername = "servername";
$username = "username";
$password = "password!";
$dbname = "DBname";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
// collect value of input field
$id = $_POST['id'];
$FirstName = $_POST['FirstName'];
$LastName = $_POST['LastName'];
$ListName = $_POST['ListName'];
$Phone = $_POST['Phone'];
$HomeAddress = $_POST['HomeAddress'];

}


$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Task1 FROM AutoPilotTaskLists WHERE 
ListName 
= ?');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $ListName);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($row) {
$Task1 = $row['Task1'];
$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Tasks 
    (FirstName, LastName, ListName, Phone, HomeAddress, Task1) 
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $FirstName, $LastName, $ListName, 
$Phone, 
$HomeAddress, $Task1);
if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "Here is the information $Task1<br />";
}
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: `Task1` is a SQL column name, not a PHP variable.

Comment: Don't call `$conn->query($sql)` twice. That will insert the row a second time. Use `if ($result)`

Comment: If you want to get the value of `Task1`, you need to execute a separate `SELECT` query and fetch the result. There's no way to get intermediate results from an `INSERT` query.

Comment: Your script is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Even if [you are escaping variables, its not safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string%5D)! You should always use [prepared statements and parameterized queries](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either MYSQLI or PDO instead of concatenating user provided values into the query.

Comment: This is all inside of a PHP script, thus the echo. But on the safety issues was planning on taking care of that later. The idea I had was to use a subquery to select the value of task1 and use the main query to insert that and variables provided by a form by the user into the tasks table. I think there's a syntax problem or something though because it doesn't submit the task1 value and says it is an undefined variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out that my first code DID submit task1 from one table to the other. I have got it working. For those that want to see what worked:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO Tasks (FirstName, LastName, ListName, Phone, 
HomeAddress, Task1) VALUES ('$FirstName', '$LastName', '$ListName', 
'$Phone', '$HomeAddress', (SELECT Task1 FROM AutoPilotTaskLists WHERE 
ListName = '$ListName'))";

$result = $conn->query("SELECT Task1 FROM AutoPilotTaskLists WHERE ListName = '$ListName'");
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  // output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$Task1 = $row["Task1"];
}}

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "Here is the information";
echo "<h2>YOUR INPUT:</h2>";
echo "$FirstName<br />
$LastName<br />
$ListName<br />
$Phone<br />
$HomeAddress<br />
$Task1<br />
";
}
```

Comment: You still never set `$Task1`, that's why you get the error message.

Comment: I just updated this answer to include the solution to that as well. THANKS!

Comment: Your code is still wide open to SQL-injection because you don't use prepared statements.

Comment: I took care of that after I posted this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do a separate `SELECT` query to get the value of `Task1`.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT Task1 FROM AutoPilotTaskLists WHERE ListName = ?');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $ListName);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
if ($row) {
    $Task1 = $row['Task1'];
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Tasks 
        (FirstName, LastName, ListName, Phone, HomeAddress, Task1) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $FirstName, $LastName, $ListName, $Phone, $HomeAddress, $Task1);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Here is the information $Task1<br />";
    }
}
```

Comment: So other than the safety issues it looks like you defined the variable of task1 with $Task1 = $row['Task1']. Then did the insert query. Would this be correct? Would the second sql query use that value or forget it?

Comment: You need to use the variable somehow.

Comment: Ok, so just doing a copy and paste I get this: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::get_result() in /path/testpage.php:34 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in /path/testpage.php on line 34

Comment: $result = $stmt->get_result(); This is line 34

Comment: What PHP version are you using? That function requires the mysqlnd driver, which has been installed by default since 5.4.

Comment: 7.3.33 is the version.

Comment: Then it should work. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php

Comment: I don't know what to tell you but it doesn't. I have edited the original post to give information on the exact code I have.

Comment: You could use the older method of `$stmt->bind_result()` followed by `$stmt->fetch()`